# Equivalents of Russian perfective/imperfective verbs

Tags: translation, perfect-aspect

Which one of the sentences means "Ne ustanovili pravila", but don't "Ne ustanavlivali pravila"?

> They didn't set rules.

or

> They didn't have to set rules.

What is the difference? Which one makes sense "Ne ustanovili pravila" in Russian?
Both words "set" means verb.

Comment: Sorry, I lost the "to".

Comment: **have** + marked infinitive =  be required to DO.  *I have to go* = I must go. So, "they did not have to set rules" means "They were not required to set rules".

Comment: I'd say that you need to more context if you want to translate them into English properly.

Comment: Context: The programmer is setting up algorithm into a calculator. He is using the software environment that means moving some direct rules from brain to machine. Then, something in program execution goes wrong. And the user is thinking: "Oh, may be there is no some necessary rules in the program, because they were skipped." And then we have a question: there were not rules setup was started at all or there is the programmer's mistake.

Comment: What does sentence "marked infinitive" means? The internet provides very strange explanation.

Comment: "They didn't have to set rules" indicates a need to have them. In your context, the issue is not whether the rules are needed, they just that were the wrong ones.

Comment: The context in your comment needs to be in your question. Having a Russian equivalent phrase in your question is OK, but it shouldn't be in the title, and not the basis of your question.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to include your context. I am also a little confused. Are you asking for the Russian equivalents? Are you asking us which are correct in Russian? Those seem off-topic to me. The intended meanings should be clear from the English-language context. But if you're simply providing the original or intended Russian, that seems ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

установить is perfective and устана́вливать is the corresponding imperfective. I am just a novice in Russian but my understanding is that they are roughly equivalent to past perfect "had established" and past simple "established". So

Не устанавливали правила - did not establish rules (past but no specific reference time)

Не установили правила - had not established rules (at a specified time of reference, the rules were not established)